# How do I add two count(*) results together on two different tables?

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have two tables: Toys and Games.

```
+--------------------+------------------+
| Field              | Type             |
+--------------------+------------------+
| toy_id             | int(10) unsigned |
| little_kid_id      | int(10) unsigned |
+--------------------+------------------+

+--------------------+------------------+
| Field              | Type             |
+--------------------+------------------+
| game_id            | int(10) unsigned |
| little_kid1        | int(10) unsigned |
| little_kid2        | int(10) unsigned |
| little_kid3        | int(10) unsigned |
+--------------------+------------------+
```

A little kid can have multiple toys.
A little kid can be participating in multiple games at once.

I want a query that will give me the total number of toys + games that a little_kid is involved with.

Basically, I want the sum of these two queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Toys WHERE little_kid_id = 900;
SELECT COUNT(*) from Games WHERE little_kid1 = 900 
                              OR little_kid2 = 900 
                              OR little_kid3 = 900;
```

Is it possible to get this in a single SQL query?  Obviously, I can sum them programmatically, but that's less desirable.

(I realize that the contrived example makes the schema look ineffecient.  Let's assume that we can't change the schema.)

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Wrap them up and use subqueries:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Toys WHERE little_kid_id = 900)+
(SELECT COUNT(*) from Games WHERE little_kid1 = 900 
                              OR little_kid2 = 900 
                              OR little_kid3 = 900)
AS SumCount
```

Voila!

Comment: how can we get it without sub-query

Comment: This won't work in Oracle without the FROM keyword. Apparently MySQL allows it!

Comment: Use following on Oracle:
`SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Toys WHERE little_kid_id = 900)+
(SELECT COUNT(*) from Games WHERE little_kid1 = 900 OR little_kid2 = 900 OR little_kid3 = 900)
AS SumCount
FROM DUAL`;

Answer (score 12):

```
SELECT
((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Toys WHERE little_kid_id = 900)+
(SELECT COUNT(*) from Games WHERE little_kid1 = 900 
                              OR little_kid2 = 900 
                              OR little_kid3 = 900))
AS Sum FROM DUAL;
```

[Selecting from the DUAL Table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries009.htm)

Comment: Provide description to your answer please.

Comment: Note: Selecting from the `dual` table is required for Oracle, but not MySQL.  Therefore, for this specific question, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/826375/6340496) is more accurate.

Comment: Isn't this the same as the accepted answer? It's just wrapped in extra parentheses

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM
(
    SELECT 1 FROM Toys WHERE little_kid_id = 900
    UNION
    SELECT 1 FROM Games WHERE little_kid1 = 900
                        OR little_kid2 = 900
                        OR little_kid3 = 900
)
```

Comment: Some explanation would help for better understanding.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on how much this query is likely to be run and how often the data changes you could periodically put data into an aggregated table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE aggregated (
    little_kid_id INT UNSIGNED,
    games_count INT UNSIGNED,
    toys_count INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (little_kid_id)
);
```

Performance wise that would be s**t hot fast and avoids any nasty sub-queries.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one...

```
db: mysql

SELECT  SUM(dum.tab) AS total FROM (
SELECT COUNT(b.category_id) AS tab FROM tblcategory AS b WHERE b.category_id=1
UNION  ALL
SELECT COUNT(a.category_id) AS tab FROM tblcategory AS a WHERE a.category_id=2
) AS dum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT  M.*,M.TOYSCOUNT+M.GAMECOUNT  
FROM (
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Toys WHERE little_kid_id) AS TOYSCOUNT,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) from Games WHERE little_kid1 = 900 OR little_kid2 = 900 OR little_kid3 = 900) AS GAMECOUNT
    ) M
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM
(
    (SELECT 1 FROM Toys WHERE little_kid_id = 900
    UNION
    SELECT 1 FROM Games WHERE little_kid1 = 900
                        OR little_kid2 = 900
                        OR little_kid3 = 900) as temptable
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select t1.tx,t2.px,t3.mx,t2.px + t3.mx  
        as total from(
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT id) as tx
FROM Customer) as t1
cross join(
select COUNT (DISTINCT name) as px
FROM details 
) as t2
cross join(
select count (distinct device_id) as mx
from detailconfig 
) as t3
```