Count 'IN' value in MySQL from multiple non-normalized columns
I am trying to count the amount of times an int or string value is presented in a table row from several columns in a non-normalized table.
SELECT count(*) from persons
WHERE '1' IN (`column 1`, `column 2`, `column 3`,`column 4`) AND person_MyId='14';

What I trying to solve is if it's possible to count the amount of times the value of 1 was located in the four columns without normalizing that table? I'm trying to see what I am missing in my query to pull that off.

you can refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826365/how-do-i-add-two-count-results-together-on-two-different-tables

Use SUM,
SELECT SUM( (col1 = 1) +  (col2 = 1) +  (col3 = 1) + (col4 = 1) ) AS totCount
FROM persons
WHERE person_MyId = 14;

See example

this worked flawlessly, thanks Basha, three thumbs up my guy.

@d-comet I am glad it helped you. Please mark as accepted so future readers can benefit from this.

Use query:
SELECT count(*) 
from persons 
WHERE person_MyId='14'
AND (
     column_1 like '%1%'
  OR column_2 like '%1%'
  OR column_3 like '%1%'
  OR column_4 like '%1%'
);

